# Do Academics use networking websites such as LinkedIn, ResearchGate, Academia.edu?

Tags: online-resource, networking, social-media

If they do use networking websites what is the typical use case (e.g., stay in touch with other academics, prospective students, find out what is the latest research development in their field)

If they do not use the networking websites what is the main reason (e.g., websites do not offer desired functionality, not interested in online professional networking)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a polling question.

Comment: It's not phrased as a poll. The question isn't "Do you use...", requesting 500 responses of "yes" or "no" but, rather, "Do academics use...", for which a single answer along the lines of the following would be entirely appropriate: "A survey by so-and-so found that X% of professors use networking sites for Y and Z purposes, and A, B and C were the most common reasons given for not using them."

Answer (score 1):

Academics are just like everybody else.  Some use social networking sites heavily, others do not.  Different people choose different sites and different ways that they use them.  There is no secret code that we academics must adhere to regarding social networking.

Comment: I wish we had a secret code. That'd be way cooler.